# AspectJ - Is is possible to extend an enum's value?

Tags: reflection, enums, aspectj

Say I have an enum

```
public enum E {A,B,C}
```

Is it possible to add another value, say `D`, by AspectJ?

After googling around, it seems that there used to be a way to hack the private static field `$VALUES`, then call the constructor(String, int) by reflection, but seems not working with 1.7 anymore.

Here are several links:
http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html (provided by @WimDeblauwe )

and this: http://www.jroller.com/VelkaVrana/entry/modify_enum_with_reflection

Comment: Not an exact answer, but maybe this helps: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html

Comment: Seems not working anymore. `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, int.class)` doesn't work. Actually `clazz.getConstructors()` returns an empty array when `clazz` is an enum.

Comment: I wonder why so many people think of AspectJ as a hacking tool. It is a clean code tool by means of modularising cross-cutting concerns. Even if what you want works somehow via reflection, why would you manipulate an enum? By design an enum is some kind of constant list of enumeration values. By breaking design principles what do you gain? Stability? Maintainability? Or just nothing useful? Sorry for this comment, but I could not resist.

Comment: @kriegaex Well the thing is, I have the source code of a game developed by another group of guys. We need to make some modifications before we run it in our region. So I need a 'clean' way to make those changes, so that it won't be a giant pain in the ass for me to merge the future version from the original dev team with my own 'hack'. So I thought AspectJ is a pretty good choice. And as for this enum, it actually contains all the commands recognized by the game server. So when I'm trying to add a new command, I have to 1)change the source code 2)try to find a way to 'hack'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I recommend you to refactor the source code, maybe adding a collection of valid region IDs to each enumeration value. This should be straightforward enough for subsequent merging if you use Git and not some old-school SCM tool like SVN.

Maybe it would even make sense to use a dynamic data structure altogether instead of an enum if it is clear that in the future the list of commands is dynamic. But that should go into the upstream code base. I am sure the devs will accept a good patch or pull request if prepared cleanly.

Remember: Trying to avoid refactoring is usually a bad smell, a symptom of an illness, not a solution. I prefer solutions to symptomatic workarounds. Clean code rules and software craftsmanship attitude demand that.

---

Having said the above, now here is what you can do. It should work under JDK 7/8 and I found it on [Jérôme Kehrli's blog](http://niceideas.ch/roller2/badtrash/entry/java_create_enum_instances_dynamically) (please be sure to add the bugfix mentioned in one of the comments below the article).

**Enum extender utility:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.util;

import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessor;
import sun.reflect.FieldAccessor;
import sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory;

public class DynamicEnumExtender {

    private static ReflectionFactory reflectionFactory =
        ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory();

    private static void setFailsafeFieldValue(Field field, Object target, Object value)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        // let's make the field accessible
        field.setAccessible(true);

        // next we change the modifier in the Field instance to
        // not be final anymore, thus tricking reflection into
        // letting us modify the static final field
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        int modifiers = modifiersField.getInt(field);

        // blank out the final bit in the modifiers int
        modifiers &= ~Modifier.FINAL;
        modifiersField.setInt(field, modifiers);

        FieldAccessor fa = reflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(field, false);
        fa.set(target, value);
    }

    private static void blankField(Class<?> enumClass, String fieldName)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        for (Field field : Class.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getName().contains(fieldName)) {
                AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[] { field }, true);
                setFailsafeFieldValue(field, enumClass, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void cleanEnumCache(Class<?> enumClass)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        blankField(enumClass, "enumConstantDirectory"); // Sun (Oracle?!?) JDK 1.5/6
        blankField(enumClass, "enumConstants"); // IBM JDK
    }

    private static ConstructorAccessor getConstructorAccessor(Class<?> enumClass, Class<?>[] additionalParameterTypes)
        throws NoSuchMethodException
    {
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[additionalParameterTypes.length + 2];
        parameterTypes[0] = String.class;
        parameterTypes[1] = int.class;
        System.arraycopy(additionalParameterTypes, 0, parameterTypes, 2, additionalParameterTypes.length);
        return reflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(enumClass .getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes));
    }

    private static Object makeEnum(Class<?> enumClass, String value, int ordinal, Class<?>[] additionalTypes, Object[] additionalValues)
        throws Exception
    {
        Object[] parms = new Object[additionalValues.length + 2];
        parms[0] = value;
        parms[1] = Integer.valueOf(ordinal);
        System.arraycopy(additionalValues, 0, parms, 2, additionalValues.length);
        return enumClass.cast(getConstructorAccessor(enumClass, additionalTypes).newInstance(parms));
    }

    /**
     * Add an enum instance to the enum class given as argument
     *
     * @param <T> the type of the enum (implicit)
     * @param enumType the class of the enum to be modified
     * @param enumName the name of the new enum instance to be added to the class
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Enum<?>> void addEnum(Class<T> enumType, String enumName) {
        // 0. Sanity checks
        if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(enumType))
            throw new RuntimeException("class " + enumType + " is not an instance of Enum");

        // 1. Lookup "$VALUES" holder in enum class and get previous enum
        // instances
        Field valuesField = null;
        Field[] fields = enumType.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().contains("$VALUES")) {
                valuesField = field;
                break;
            }
        }
        AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[] { valuesField }, true);

        try {

            // 2. Copy it
            T[] previousValues = (T[]) valuesField.get(enumType);
            List<T> values = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(previousValues));

            // 3. build new enum
            T newValue = (T) makeEnum(
                enumType,                         // The target enum class
                enumName,                         // THE NEW ENUM INSTANCE TO BE DYNAMICALLY ADDED
                values.size(), new Class<?>[] {}, // could be used to pass values to the enum constuctor if needed
                new Object[] {}                   // could be used to pass values to the enum constuctor if needed
            );

            // 4. add new value
            values.add(newValue);

            // 5. Set new values field
            setFailsafeFieldValue(valuesField, null, values.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(enumType, 0)));

            // 6. Clean enum cache
            cleanEnumCache(enumType);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample application & enum:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

/** In honour of "The Secret of Monkey Island"... ;-) */
public enum Command {
    OPEN, CLOSE, PUSH, PULL, WALK_TO, PICK_UP, TALK_TO, GIVE, USE, LOOK_AT, TURN_ON, TURN_OFF
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Server {
    public void executeCommand(Command command) {
        System.out.println("Executing command " + command);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Client {
    private Server server;

    public Client(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void issueCommand(String command) {
        server.executeCommand(
            Command.valueOf(
                command.toUpperCase().replace(' ', '_')
            )
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client(new Server());
        client.issueCommand("use");
        client.issueCommand("walk to");
        client.issueCommand("undress");
        client.issueCommand("sleep");
    }
}
```

**Console output with original enum:**

```
Executing command USE
Executing command WALK_TO
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant de.scrum_master.app.Command.UNDRESS
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Command.valueOf(Command.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Client.issueCommand(Client.java:12)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Client.main(Client.java:22)
```

Now you can either add an aspect with an advice executed after the enum class was loaded or just call this manually in your application before extended enum values are to be used for the first time. Here I am showing how it can be done in an aspect.

**Enum extender aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Command;
import de.scrum_master.util.DynamicEnumExtender;

public aspect CommandExtender {
    after() : staticinitialization(Command) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        DynamicEnumExtender.addEnum(Command.class, "UNDRESS");
        DynamicEnumExtender.addEnum(Command.class, "SLEEP");
        DynamicEnumExtender.addEnum(Command.class, "WAKE_UP");
        DynamicEnumExtender.addEnum(Command.class, "DRESS");
    }
}
```

**Console output with extended enum:**

```
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Command.<clinit>)
Executing command USE
Executing command WALK_TO
Executing command UNDRESS
Executing command SLEEP
```

Et voilà! `;-)`

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work. Looks like it's still the old trick of getting the constructor and the static field $VALUES, which wasn't working in 1.7. Anyway I'll try it out when I have time.

Comment: As for the refactoring, the thing is it's a giant plain Java project written from ground zero, e.g. they even wrote their own ORM layer. To make things worse, the only comments I see is `//TODO`, and there isn't really enough unit tests there. I guess it might all sound like excuses to others, but the fact is it'll take me at least weeks(or maybe a month or two) before I'm confident enough to do any serious refactoring, which I don't have right now. It's just one of the many games we have at hand. Anyway thanks for your help, I'll try it out to see if it works when I have time.

Comment: I tested with Java 7 and 8 and both worked. As for the refactoring, I meant you to limit it to extending the enum, which is what my solution also does, but in a very hacky way. The refactoring cannot be as complex as you may fear. Refactoring starts small and adds one step at a time. You apply a boyscout rule: Leave the camp ground behind cleaner than you found it. That's all. I have coached so many teams who told me the same as you did. (I am an agile coach.) Believe me, there is a lot of bad code out there everywhere, not just in your company. And those teams managed to improve it. Amen. ;-)

Comment: I guess you're right, maybe all this not touching the source code but 'hacking' around with AspectJ thing is just that I don't wanna spend more time on it :) Hell I don't even understand what 80% of the code is doing at the moment. So thanks for you advice, it was helpful :)

Comment: As for this enum thing, I guess I'm more like curious, to see if it's possible at all (in the end I can always edit the source code, just a single line of code. One single line can't really be that hard to merge :) )

Comment: Curiosity is a good thing and one of the main reasons I am here at SO at all.